# Qt - How to Remove the selected Row from the QTableView and copy it to the QLineEdit

Tags: qt, qtableview, qt4.7, model-view, qlineedit

I have 3 `QLineEdit`s (say Name, Address & Phone No.), 2 `QPushButton` (Add & Modify) and a `QTableView`.

When I enter text in all the `QLineEdit`s, and if I click the Add button, all 3 texts of the `QLineEdit`s should be added in the 1st row of the `QTableView`.
Again if I enter 3 text's in the `QLineEdit` and the Add Button is Clicked, the Text's should be placed in the 2nd row of the `QTableView`. Like this it should go on. I did this all and it works fine.

Now if I select any row from the `QTableView` and once I click the Modify Button the selected Row has to be removed from the `QTableView` and the Items should be again placed in their respective `QLineEdit`s.

How can I do this ?

Example.h

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

namespace Ui {
class Example;
}

class Example : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Example (QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Example();

private slots:
    void on_addButton_released();
    void on_modifyButton_released();

private:
    Ui::Example*ui;
    QStandardItemModel *model;
};

#endif // EXAMPLE_H
```

EXAMPLE.CPP

```
#include "Example.h"

Example::Example(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Example)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    model = new QStandardItemModel();

    ui->tableView->setModel(model);

}

Example::~Example()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Example::on_addButton_released()
{
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString(" NAME ")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString(" ADDRESS ")));
    model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QStandardItem(QString(" PHONE NO ")));

    QStandardItem *nameItem = new QStandardItem(ui->nameLineEdit->text());
    QStandardItem *addressItem = new QStandardItem(ui->addressLineEdit->text());
    QStandardItem *phoneItem = new QStandardItem(ui->phoneLineEdit->text());

    QList<QStandardItem*> row;
    row << nameItem << addressItem << phoneItem;

    model->appendRow(row);

    ui->nameLineEdit->clear();
    ui->addressLineEdit->clear();
    ui->mobileLineEdit->clear();
    ui->emailLineEdit->clear();
}

void Example::on_modifyButton_released()
{


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is when the Modify button is clicked, access the selection from the `QItemSelectionModel` of your `QTableView`. Once you have the selection, if any, process it.

For example:

```
void Example::on_modifyButton_released()
{
    if( ui->myTableView )
    {
         QModelIndex currentIndex = ui->myTableView->selectionModel();

         // Make sure to check the index is valid, as the user
         // may not have selected a row.
         if( currentRow.isValid() )
         {
              // Add your code here to copy the data to 
              // your QLineEdit and remove the row from your
              // QStandardModel.
              ...                  
         }
    }
}
```

For reference:

`QTableView` http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QTableView.html

`QItemSelectionModel` http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QItemSelectionModel.html